# Is there any authoritative reference on what exceptions can be thrown by Matlab's built-in functions?

Tags: exception, matlab

For example, I want to catch a couldn't-read-a-file-at-that-path exception from imread().  I can do this.

```
imagePath = 'a_picture.jpg';
try
    im = imread(imagePath);
catch exception
    if strcmp(exception.identifier, 'MATLAB:imread:fileOpen')
        fprintf('Couldn''t open %s.\n', imagePath);
        im = [];
    else
        fprintf('Unexpected error (%s): %s\n', ...
                exception.identifier, exception.message);
        throw(exception);
    end
end
```

But the only ways I know to discover the magic string to compare with ('MATLAB:imread:fileOpen' in this case), are:

1. Cause the error, catch the exception, and look at the identifier.  But it would take a long time to do this right.  For example, does Matlab use a different exception identifier if the file exists but is not actually an image file?  How about if it exists but I don't have read permission?  What if it's a directory?
2. Look at the source code.  imread() is written in Matlab, so this is possible, but it wouldn't be for other functions.  And of course imread() calls *other* functions that are not written in Matlab, and exceptions could bubble up from them.

Is there any authoritative way for me to know all the exceptions imread() can throw?  I'm hoping this is in the documentation somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [MATLAB: A reference about error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562698/matlab-a-reference-about-error-messages)

Comment: Why does it matter which exception is thrown?  It either worked or it did not, right?

Comment: A better question: why do you need to identify the error with such specificity, when all you're really doing with it is effectively rethrowing it?

Comment: @gnovice & MatlabDoug - in this case, it may not matter, but you might want variant handling depending on the type of error.  If it doesn't matter, why does Matlab recommend & use error IDs?

Comment: BTW - I don't believe that this is a duplicate.  He wants a reference of what throws what.  The other question asked what they meant.

Comment: The problem is that is _not_ in the documentation anywhere.  And as Matlab is proprietary, _and_ the documentation is usually actually good, there is no other comprehensive documentation out there, even less an authoritative.  To the next one: Please do not bother to search through the Mathworks site on this.  I only hope that there is a resource out there I just do not happen to know.

Comment: To get a comprehensive list of errors, note that each ofthe matlab error messages start with MATLAB: -- you should be able to do something like find /Applications/MATLAB_R2010b.app/ | while read x; do echo $x; strings $x | grep "MATLAB:"; done

Comment: @gnovice, I'm no MATLAB expert, but it looks to me like he is singling out one specific exception to NOT re-throw it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

The problem is that even if there would be an authoritative reference on what a given function in MatLab throws, it could change from version to version.  So even if you could do it, you probably should not.

I would recommend only checking for the ones that you know you can handle, and generate some generic errors for others (or reuse what MatLab gives you).

---

Some comments based on other languages/frameworks:

In .NET, the only list of exceptions that can be thrown from a method, is in documentation, and is not liked to the source code.  These are often out of date, invalid, and incomplete.

In Java, you can specify what exception is thrown form what method.  This is then verified by the compiler, and therefore an authoritative reference can be built by the compiler.  MatLab lacks such a feature, therefore the best you can do is searching as outlined in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I search for that, and I did not find anything... The only thing I see it could help you, would be analyse the source code of `imread`, which I don't think it's possible. However, you could always try to see the source code of the same function in [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index.html), since it almost the same (I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to enumerate files to generate your own reference, try

```
grep -r "MATLAB:" <matlab root>
```

you'll get a long list...but it appears errors are either thrown by `error()` or `mexErrMsgIdAndTxt`.  Those plus function names let you be more specific.  Pretty slow though.

`grep` will also note that some binary files match.  Feed it `-a` and it will be able to pull out the error messages from many of them.